# How to set multiple shufflegrouping for a bolt dynamically?

Tags: apache-storm

I want to read topology from an xml file in which for a bolt i have the spouts and bolts from which it consumes.To add each spout and bolt that the bolt consumes from we need to do the shufflegrouping. Since I'm trying to do it from xml file this should happen dynamically.But if I do something like below It gives an error because everytime it enters loop we are trying to create a new bolt with same boltid.

```
TopologyBuilder tp = new TopologyBuilder();
for(String boltconsumes : spoutsAndBoltsFromXml ){
        tp.setBolt(boltid,  boltclass ,boltexecutors).shufflegrouping(boltconsumes);
}
```

So I tried something like this.

```
TopologyBuilder tp = new TopologyBuilder();
BoltDeclarer tp1 = tp.setBolt(boltid,  boltclass ,boltexecutors)
for(String boltconsumes : spoutsAndBoltsFromXml ){
        tp1= tp1.shufflegrouping(boltconsumes);
}
```

From this I get a tp1 as BoltDeclarer, but I have my spout at tp.setSpout() and also I would return tp.createtopology().How do I use the tp1 that I got here to embed it in tp.Is there any other way to do shufflegrouping dynamically.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your approach is basically fine. Of course, you need to all add spouts and bolt in a loop, too. What is you XML format?

Comment: Thanks Matthias. I was mistaken by thinking changes on tp1 wouldn't reflected on tp. Where as it does.It just works fine.